# Video dosen't play at all. [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

Im trying to read a local file with videos. Here is the code. I used array to add the videos and play it in sequence but it didn't play any video.

```
 var videos = new Array(); //("BigBuck.m4v","Video.mp4","BigBuck.m4v","Video2.mp4");
var currentVideo = 0;

function nextVideo() {
    // get the element
    videoElement = document.getElementById("play-video");
    // remove the event listener, if there is one
    videoElement.removeEventListener('ended', nextVideo, false);

    // update the source with the currentVideo from the videos array
    videoElement.src = videos[currentVideo];
    // play the video

    videoElement.play()

    // increment the currentVideo, looping at the end of the array
    currentVideo = (currentVideo + 1) % videos.length

    // add an event listener so when the video ends it will call the nextVideo function again
    videoElement.addEventListener('ended', nextVideo, false);
}

function yesnoCheck() {
    document.getElementById("filepicker").style.display = 'none';
}

// add change event to pick up selected files
document.getElementById("filepicker").addEventListener("change", function (event) {

    var files = event.target.files;
    // loop through files
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        // select the filename for any videos
        if (files[i].type == "video/mp4") {
            // add the filename to the array of videos
            videos.push(files[i].name); // work from webkitRelativePath;
        }
    };

    // once videos are loaded initialize and play the first one
    nextVideo();

}, false);
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to read a local file. It wont work if you set the `<video>` src to the name of that file. You have to read the file using `FileReader`.

Comment: How do i apply file reader to that code? Im new in javascript so yeah thanks alot

Comment: @ItsGreg //////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to read the contents of the video, not just set the `src` to it's name. You can do so by using the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

I've adjusted your code, but I haven't tested it. Here's a working example on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zmq2u4c/), though.

```
var videos = new Array(); //("BigBuck.m4v","Video.mp4","BigBuck.m4v","Video2.mp4");
var currentVideo = 0;
var reader = new FileReader();
// get th eelement
var videoElement = document.getElementById("play-video");


function nextVideo() {
    // remove the event listener, if there is one
    videoElement.removeEventListener('ended', nextVideo, false);

    // read the file contents as a data URL
    reader.readAsDataURL(videos[currentVideo]);

    // increment the currentVideo, looping at the end of the array
    currentVideo = (currentVideo + 1) % videos.length

    // add an event listener so when the video ends it will call the nextVideo function again
    videoElement.addEventListener('ended', nextVideo, false);
}

function yesnoCheck() {
    document.getElementById("filepicker").style.display = 'none';
}

// add change event to pick up selected files
document.getElementById("filepicker").addEventListener("change", function (event) {

    var files = event.target.files;
    // loop through files
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        // select the filename for any videos
        if (files[i].type == "video/mp4") {
            // add the whole file to the array
            videos.push(files[i]);
        }
    };
    // once videos are loaded initialize and play the first one
    nextVideo();

}, false);
// once the file is fully read
reader.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // you have the data URL in reader.result
    videoElement.src = reader.result;
    // play the video
    videoElement.play()
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but it dosen't seem to work :/

Comment: @ChlovenTan oops, made a typo. It should be working now ;)

Comment: Very bad idea to convert a video through a fileReader. Use `URL.createObjectURL(yourFile)` to create a temporary uri usable in the page by media elements.